# Local Drives showing under Other Locations in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10 and then I opened Ubuntu after shutting down Windows 10. Both of my OS are installed on my SSD and other local drives are on HDD. the local drives are being shown under Other Locations section of Ubuntu and I am able to access the drives but not able to cut,copy or paste within those drives or any external drives.

[image: Drives are under other locations]

Is there any way I can have the drives outside Other Locations without formatting or any way I can get the option to cut,copy or paste?

Comment: Local drives under "Other Locations" is the default behaviour in newer versions of Files (Nautilus). It's most likely unrelated to your actual problem: not being able to cut/copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You cant write to your Windows disks because Windows has an hybrid shutdown

You must shut down Windows completely
Under windows Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while clicking on the shutdown button

You may also disable the 'Fast Startup' feature of Windows

[image]